# EXTJS- Grid column sorting - sort the null values of columns at the bottom of the grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7-classic

[image]

While sorting the EmpNo column either ASC/DESC, null values should be avoided so that it will be at the end of the grid.

This code just helped to reverse the sorting logic:

```
if(v1 < v2 || !v1) {
    return -1;
 }
        
 if(v1 > v2 || !v2) {
     return 1;
 }
        
 return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code. With this modification, the null values of the 'empNo' column will be sorted at the bottom of the grid when you click on the column header to sort.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: [{
            EmpNo: 3,
            name: 'Lisa',
            email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-111-1224'
        }, {
            EmpNo: 2,
            name: 'Bart',
            email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1234'
        }, {
            EmpNo: null,
            name: 'Homer',
            email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1244'
        }, {
            EmpNo: 1,
            name: 'Marge',
            email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1254'
        }, {
            EmpNo: null,
            name: 'george',
            email: 'george@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1244'
        }]
    });
    
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            text: 'EmpNo',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'EmpNo',
            sorter: function (data1, data2) {
                var empNo1 = data1.get('EmpNo'),
                    empNo2 = data2.get('EmpNo'),
                    direction = this.getDirection();
    
                if (empNo1 == empNo2) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (empNo1 === null) {
                    return direction == 'ASC' ? 1 : -1;
                }
    
                if (empNo2 === null) {
                    return direction == 'ASC' ? -1 : 1;
                }
    
                return empNo1 > empNo2 ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],
        height: 400,
        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```